# Neo4j treating two different objects as one, because they extend the same parent

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I currently have two objects which have a lot of common properties, so I created a parent object and moved all the common properties into the parent, however now when I look inside the neo database, it treats the parent as it's own object and makes all my nodes look like they're one type.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Cat extends Parent {
    private int legs;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Car extends Parent {
    private int wheels;
}

public class Parent {
    private int id;
    private Stirng name;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by one type? They should have different labels on them?

Comment: In neo browser, all my nodes have two labels, cat and parent or car and parent, is there a way to just make it cat or car and remove the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid inheriting labels because of the class hierarchy, you can make `Parent` abstract, or an interface. Then, the `Parent` label will not be added to `Cat` and `Car`
The rules for label inheritance can be read here: https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:node-entity

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does OGM tell you, they are the same?
Can you show, how you initialize the objects? Or do you load them from the Database?

Basically OGM decides if two objects are the same, using the id or the `equals` function, depending on the situation.

Since your id is an `int` instead of an `Integer` or `Long`, it gets initialized per default with 0.
Meaning, if you now try to save those objects, OGM thinks they're the same.
Maybe that is whats causing your problem.

Comment: Labeling my parent as abstract has resolved it, just in the browser, it says I have 3 labels and when I run a query, the color for the two different nodes are the same color, because of the parent

Comment: Ok. If its just the color of the nodes, thats just the CSS from the Neo4j Browser. You should be able to change that, if you click one of the labels in the database information in the fold-out view on the left. Still, OGM adds each non-abstract class in the hierachy as a label, so using an abstract class seems best.